# Reset Cookie Consent Message

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, cookieconsent

So I use a standard Cookie Consent on my pages generated by https://cookieconsent.insites.com/download/
Though I would like that the cookie consent reappears every time someone loads the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may not such a clean way but it deletes / resets the cookie

```
    <?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("COOKIENAME", "", time() - 3600);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Documentation at https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/

According to this it should be something like:

```
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "cookie": {
    expiryDays: 0
  },
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#f1d600"
    }
  }
});
```

So set `cookie.expiryDays`to `0` maybe should do the job.

Comment: I already did that. 0 is not an accepted property and the only one thats accepted is from 1 (day) until -1 (infinity). When i set it to 0 cookieconsent_status is overwritten by the imported js script. so i changed it there to and got the normal 365 days out of it

Comment: okay... I think that's all possibilities they give you, you will have to change the cookieconsent code to work like you expect it... But why do you want to have the message on every pageload?

Comment: Cause my page works with a game interface witch uses cookies for its data exceptions like ports for the game servers etc to be remembered and i want useres to see that and how they work

Comment: I made a solution up on my own with php: 
  setcookie("cookieconsent_status", "", time() - 3600);   so it gets set and on page reload it gets reset. Its not clean but it works

Comment: that's a really dirty way ;-)

Comment: but i don't know another way neither a solution. And i need to finish tonight xD